# Use global environment variables to change Jenkins constants in shared-library

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries

So I have 2 Jenkins instances and I want them to use the same shared-library for common Constants, but change some Constants depending on the environment. I thought of defining a global environment variable, e.g. `INSTANCE` and have that control which variables I need to tweak in the shared library. I tried :

**vars/Constants.groovy**

```
class Constants {
    static String FOO = "common"
    static String MAIN_REGION = System.getenv("INSTANCE") == "site2" ? "eu-central-1" : "us-east-1"
}
```

This didn't work - The environment variable `INSTANCE` looks ok outside the shared-library, but when running inside, it's empty.

I've tried to print all the environment variables and the list of very short, unlike when I run it outside the shared-library -

```
System.getenv().each { println it}
```

Now, I partly achieved what I wanted by writing a method like this -

**vars/Constants.groovy**

```
class Constants {
    static void init(script) {
        if (script.env.INSTANCE == "site2") {
            MAIN_REGION = 'eu-central-1'
        }
    }

    static String FOO = "common"
    static String MAIN_REGION = "us-east-1"
```

And load the library like this -

**Jenkinsfile**

```
@Library('shared-library') _
Constants.init(this)
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                echo Constants.MAIN_REGION
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

But it's getting complicated when the `Constants.groovy` file is larger, and some Constants are depending on each other (like a Constants that makes a list from 2 previous one, I would need to force everyone to use `init()` if I don't want to duplicate the logic)

Any ideas how I can achieve something like that?

Comment: You can access the value of the globally define environment variables using the following groovy script (that can be used in your shared lib): `Jenkins.instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()[0].getEnvVars()['INSTANCE']`